# Azure - Enable Backup on VM with Windows Server 2019 Core server, D4s_v3 sku, is failing with code BMSUserErrorContainerObjectNotFound

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, backup, azure-backup-vault

```
Azure VM Details :
OS : Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Core
Size: Standard D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)
Location: Australia East
VM generation: V1
Agent status: Ready
Agent version: 2.7.41491.1010
Azure disk encryption: Not Enabled

Extensions already installed :
DependencyAgentWindows
IaaSAntimalware
MDE.Windows
MicrosoftMonitoringAgent
```

Have an existing recovery services vault with 10s of other VMs getting backed up.

Trying to enable the backup from Azure Portal for this VM ( From the VM Blade > Operations >  Backup ) but it's failing with the following error code:

I have tried it multiple times.

```
Provisioning state: Failed
Duration: 1 minute 3 seconds
Status: Conflict
```

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BMSUserErrorContainerObjectNotFound",
      "message": "Item not found"
    }
  ]
}
```

All the information on troubleshooting backup relates issues @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-troubleshoot talk about After the "Enable Backup" step.

I have also tried to enable the backup using azure cli:

```
az backup protection enable-for-vm --vm "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm_name" -v vaultname -g vault_resourcegroup -p backuppolicy_name
```

It throws the following error:

```
The specified Azure Virtual Machine Not Found. Possible causes are
               1. VM does not exist
               2. The VM name or the Service name needs to be case sensitive
               3. VM is already Protected with same or other Vault.
                  Please Unprotect VM first and then try to protect it again.

            Please contact Microsoft for further assistance.
```

None of the Point 1,2 or 3 are true.
VM exists, the name is used as shown in the portal, no other VM protection service is in use.

Note: I have faced this issue a few days back on another subscription, but luckily no one was yet using that VM, so I destroyed and re-deployed the VM, and the error went away.
I can't do the same for this VM as it's already in use.

Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a portal error or the VM is not able to communicate with Azure Platform. I would suggest you try the "Reapply" feature to update the platform status.

[Snippet of Reapply in Azure Porta][1]

Else, you can try initiating a backup from the "Recovery Services vaults" blade and add the VM to it.

Comment: Hi Sravan, thanks for your reply. Unlikely to be a portal error because this is failing from Terraform apply too. Terraform apply goes on for 40+ min and aborts. This also fails when trying to enable backup protection from azure cli.

Edited the original question with the azure cli error and details.

Comment: The URL for your snippet is missing, and thus your image isn’t available.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to contact Microsoft support. Their engineer after some analysis ( aka to and fro, screenshots exchange over email..etc) replied with:

`I check from the backend and notice that the VM status is not in synchronize state. I’ve requested the VM engineer xxxxx resync the VM from the backend. Please try to reenable the VM backup again in the Azure portal recovery service Vault page. If you encounter the same issue, please try to configure the VM backup in the Azure Virtual Machine Panel page and let me know the results.  Thanks!`

After this when I attempted to enable the backup it worked.

So for anyone who faces this problem, it looks like the only option is to get in touch with MS Support.